# Why are my images not displaying inline

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm not sure how to get my images to display inline (as in next to each other horizontally). Presently they are below each other. My idea was to have a wrapper for the whole page then a div for the images 'homepageImageBanner' and just use display-inline for that div but maybe I need to target the images specifically to display them inline?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.homepageImageBanner {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.homepageImageBannerList {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.sgaBadge {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0;
}
.lgaBadge {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 0;
}
.egLogo {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Images -->
  <div class="homepageImageBanner">
    <ul class="homepageImageBannerList">
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.sga.org/" target="_blank">
          <img class="sgaBadge" alt="sga logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.lga.org.uk/" target="_blank">
          <img class="lgaBadge" alt="lga logo" src="http://placehold.it/120x120" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://eg.com/" target="_blank">
          <img class="egLogo" alt="eg logo" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try adding `.homepageImageBannerList li{display:inline-block;}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because li is `block` element. Change it to inline

```
.homepageImageBannerList li{
 display:inline-block
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mk0ap2nc/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
.homepageImageBanner {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.homepageImageBannerList {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.homepageImageBannerList li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sgaBadge {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0;
}
.lgaBadge {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 0;
}
.egLogo {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Images -->
  <div class="homepageImageBanner">
    <ul class="homepageImageBannerList">
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.sga.org/" target="_blank">
          <img class="sgaBadge" alt="sga logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.lga.org.uk/" target="_blank">
          <img class="lgaBadge" alt="lga logo" src="http://placehold.it/120x120" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://eg.com/" target="_blank">
          <img class="egLogo" alt="eg logo" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Since `li` is actually a `block` level element, you just needed to add `display: inline-block;` to the `li` elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
.homepageImageBanner {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

=> the div has a with of 80% of the containing element, i.e. no two of them will fit in a row, which results in displaying them below each other.

Comment: this will not make the images "next to each other". @Sowmya's answer is correct. Also sometimes better to give a *fiddle* with your answer as well.